# Ftp server in termux

Tags: ftp, termux

How can I access termux files using ftp? I wants to write files using ftp, so i can use good editor for edit files.

My question is how can I set up my ftp server in termux?

Comment: Ftp is not working the way it should be, And only if you want to edit your files then you can use file manager to access your file. here is the helping link : https://www.learntermux.tech/2020/10/Termux-File-Manager.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to start ftp server in termux, for starting server you have to use tcpsvd for binding port.
`tcpsvd -Ev localhost 8023 ftpd /sdcard`

Now open ftp client or go to browser with ftp://localhost:8023

It will show all sdcard content, use more ftpd option to explore ftp.